# Incorporar últimas fotos Instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, instagram-api

Preciso incorporar em um site, as últimas 6 fotos de um perfil do Instagram.

Eu preciso de algo deste tipo:
[image: thumbs das ultimas 5 fotos de um perfil]

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim. Existe a API do instagram que você pode utilizar:

http://instagram.com/developer/

Até exemplos em diversas linguagens de programação.

Comment: Sim, porém não estou entendendo como faço para autorizar o meu app...

Comment: Qual a linguagem que você está utilizando?

Nesta página há uma explicação sobre a autenticação e um link para OAuth 2.0. Independente da linguagem, você irá utilizar o OAuth 2.0 para autenticar sua aplicação.